# How to map my model objects to the FirebaseObjectObservables?

Tags: angular, typescript, angularfire2

I was wondering how can I map my model typed objects to the response that firebase gives me.

The examples given in the docs are really simple and clear but they don't map the responses to Custom Typed Objects.

Let's say I have this

```
export class TestComponent{
    boxes: FirebaseListObservable<any[]>;
    constructor(private af: AngularFire) {
        this.boxes = af.database.list('/boxes');        
    }
 }
```

like the docs tells me to do, but I want to give custom behavior to my boxes and have a class that does something like this.

```
class Box{
    constructor(){}

    setName(){ console.log("I want my boxes from firebase to have that behavior"); }
}
```

Is there a way to automagically map the firebase responses to my Box Object. What I would want to do, is something like this if possible but it doesn't seems to exists.

```
class Box extends FirebaseObjectOservable{...}
```

Thanks a lot !